# What parts of .NET require administrative privileges to be executed?

Tags: .net, windows-7, uac

Which parts of the framework require a user to be more than a Standard User? The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to compile a list of possible issues with our existing applications when migrating to Windows 7.

Now, I can think of a few things myself:

- Writing to Eventlog
- Writing to Registry Keys outside of Current_User scope
- Getting an Environment variable
- etc...

I really would like a more complete list and so far I've not come across a decent resource in which all this stuff is listed.

Note that I'm not looking for ways of elevating the privileges for the existing apps (which can be done by using a manifest), I'm simply identifying actions in code that might cause issues.

Comment: as an aside, of course these limitations are not specific to .Net

Comment: none of the examples you specify necessarily require admin privileges. Applications can add their own log to the event log system and specify lower privilege level. getting an environment variable is per-user operation. writing to registry keys outside of the HKCU depends on the registry ACL; applications can certainly create HKLM keys that are writable by any user.

Comment: It seems very hard to get a complete list of API calls that would potentially cause problems. I will have to focus on other means of determining if an application would fail. THe way it looks now, it seems Daniel Rose has offered the best lead to solving my problem, but it's not really the answer to my question. Since Markus pointed out that the list is basically the same as the NT Logo requirements  I will grant him the bounty. Thanks everybody for your input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, your examples don't really have anything to do with Windows 7 or .NET. Actually they were already part of the "Designed for Windows NT 4.0" logo requirements. If you have written your application in a way that non-admin users were able to run it on NT, Win2k or XP, it will just work fine on Vista/Win7.

There is another common pitfall when you run your software on x64 systems (however this too isn't specific to Win7 but is true e. g. for Win2003 Server x64 or Win XP x64 as well): If you are working with native 32-bit code, like calls to a native DLL or COM interop with a in-process component), make sure to select "x86" as the platform target in Visual Studio project settings instead of "Any CPU". Otherwise your application will run as a 64 bit process, and you can't mix 32 and 64 bit code in the same process, so you would run into errors.

And of course, as it always has been best practice, use `Environment.GetSpecialFolders` instead of hard-coded paths.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Alex - "Well, your examples don't really have anything to do with Windows 7 or .NET". There are no .Net framework parts that require administrative privileges. There are framework classes, which wrap OS functionality that might require admin privileges. However, there's no easy way to say whether particular .Net method will get to such a feature.

Answer (score 8):

Thinking of it as "What library calls" is going to lead you down the wrong path. Think about anything that writes to a file. If that file is under Program Files (among other places), you need admin privs. If it's under AppData, you don't. Same library call, different outcomes. Ditto for writing to the registry - HKLM you need admin, HKCU you don't. Writing to Event Log is generally ok but creating your event source is not. And so on. It's not about what method you call, it's more about the params (eg path) you pass to it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe getting environment variables need elevating privledges. At least I've never run into it, are there really cases where that's true?

Comment: You may be right. My approach was to first compile a list of possible painpoints and then determine for each of them whether or not I run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

One place to get a partial list is to look in the "Local Group Policy Editor" where you can check what Logon rights and Privileges are only assigned to administrators by default.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Since Corp.IT has a tendency to overuse the policies at my client's site, this might lead to good results as well.

Answer (score 2):

Named Pipes can cause issues.  Normally this isn't an issue, but use of Named Pipes is now increasing with WCF supporting them natively for IPC transport.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add that to my list as well.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in .Net framework requires administrative privileges. Everything that has to do with user-level security is controlled by the OS, and whether admin privileges are required is a matter of OS configuration. Thus, the framework can't make the determination whether it needs to require elevation.

You should be thinking not in terms of "What in the .Net framework requires elevation?", but in terms of "What OS features is my app using that require admin elevation in the default configuration". And as @Marcus said, "Designed for Windows NT 4.0" logo requirements is a very good starting point to determine which OS features your app should be avoiding if it's designed to run as regular user.

Comment: Point taken. The thing is, if I can narrow it down to a set of libraries, it will become possible to scan (all) codebases on the occurance of any of those, which would quickly indicate possible issues.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but it'll be hard to automatically scan and flag such calls. Mostly because the admin elevation often is triggered not by the method call itself, but by the parameters passed to that method call.

Comment: Admin elevation isn't triggered by method calls at all. What might be triggered is "failing if you aren't elevated". Those are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Luapriv checks from the [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371695%28VS.85%29.aspx) to help you find issues. Also the [Standard User Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765948%28WS.10%29.aspx) will help you.

Comment: Those are great resources. They will certainly help me a lot in getting my job done. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, these tools are part of the Application Compatibility Toolkit: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24DA89E9-B581-47B0-B45E-492DD6DA2971&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, Visual Studio can calculate this for you...

Just go to your project's properties, click on Security tab and check "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings" checkbox. Select "This is a partial trust application" radio button and then click on "Calculate Permissions" button.

VS will place a checkmark next to each permission like IO, Registry, etc your application requires...

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt there is a way to get a complete list of .NET calls that require elevation of privileges.

BTW writing to the Event Log doesn't require elevation, however creating an Event Log source does require elevation.

The best way to find out which parts of your code have issues is by testing on Win7  and see what breaks, not elegant but does the job.  If you are looking to create time estimates for this task, then you might have to spend a day or two hacking through your app:  run on Win7, see what breaks, make note of it, comment/avoid/disable that section, and repeat until you think you have enough a of list of things to address.

Comment: If it were only a single app I'm checking I agree that your approach would be good. However, we're talking about 250+ applications unfortunately. And I want to prevent having to run all of them one by one.

Comment: Then you totally want the LUA (or standard user) analyser, it will watch the app run and tell you what it's doing. Get the toolkit from the links in the other answer for sure.